# Give an example to show that $f_n$ fails to converge to $f$ uniformly over $S$ if $S$ is not compact

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, compactness

Given the theorem: Suppose $S \subset \Bbb R^n$ is compact, and $P$ is an equicontinuous sequence of functions ($f_n$) over $S$ converging pointwise to a function $f$ at each $x \in S$, then $f_n$ converges to $f$ uniformly over $S$.

Note that the definition here is: $Q$ as a set of real-valued functions defined over $S \subset \Bbb R^n$ is equicontinuous at $y \in S$ if given $\epsilon \gt 0$ there is a $\delta \gt 0$ such that $|f(x)-f(y)|\lt \epsilon$ for all $|x-y|\lt \delta$ and all $f \in Q$. Also, it is equicontinuous over $S$ if it is equicontinuous at all $x \in S$

I want to give an example to show that the above theorem fails **if $S$ is not compact** but stuck on finding one. Could someone provide an example please？Thanks a lot.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Rbuhdo0AZDU ​ ​

Comment: I'm not sure what the video is implying, could you explain further please

Comment: It's implying a family of functions for which "the above theorem fails" when the upper slinky continues infinitely far to the right. ​ ​